# Node Manager is reachable but the managed server is not reachable

Tags: docker, weblogic12c

I'm facing a problem when configuring multi-host environment on docker machine. I have two machines Master and  Worker. The worker has node manager running and is reachable from the Master. But the managed server running on the worker machine is not reachable.

[image]

Can anyone help me through this.

Docker file:

```
# LICENSE CDDL 1.0 + GPL 2.0
#
# Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# ORACLE DOCKERFILES PROJECT
# --------------------------
# This Dockerfile extends the Oracle WebLogic image by creating a sample domain.
#
# The 'base-domain' created here has Java EE 7 APIs enabled by default:
#  - JAX-RS 2.0 shared lib deployed
#  - JPA 2.1, 
#  - WebSockets and JSON-P
#
# Util scripts are copied into the image enabling users to plug NodeManager 
# magically into the AdminServer running on another container as a Machine.
#
# HOW TO BUILD THIS IMAGE
# -----------------------
# Put all downloaded files in the same directory as this Dockerfile
# Run: 
#      $ sudo docker build -t 1213-domain --build-arg ADMIN_PASSWORD=welcome1 .
#

# Pull base image
# ---------------
FROM oracle/weblogic:12.1.3-developer

# Maintainer
# ----------
MAINTAINER Bruno Borges <bruno.borges@oracle.com>

# WLS Configuration
# -------------------------------
ARG ADMIN_PASSWORD
ENV DOMAIN_NAME="base_domain" \
    DOMAIN_HOME="/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain" \
    JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -server -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dapplication.properties.location=/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain -DFundCenterProperties.Location=/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/FundCenterProperties.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/log4j.properties" \
    ADMIN_PORT="7007" \
    ADMIN_HOST="wlsadmin" \
    NM_PORT="5556" \
    MS_PORT="7003" \
    CONFIG_JVM_ARGS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true" \
    PATH=$PATH:/u01/oracle/oracle_common/common/bin:/u01/oracle/wlserver/common/bin:/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin:/u01/oracle

# Add files required to build this image
USER root
COPY container-scripts/* /u01/oracle/


USER oracle
# Configuration of WLS Domain
WORKDIR /u01/oracle
RUN /u01/oracle/wlst /u01/oracle/create-wls-domain.py && \
    mkdir -p /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/security && \
    echo "username=weblogic" > /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties && \ 
    echo "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" >> /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties && \
    echo ". /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.sh" >> /u01/oracle/.bashrc && \ 
    echo "export PATH=$PATH:/u01/oracle/wlserver/common/bin:/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin" >> /u01/oracle/.bashrc && \
    cp /u01/oracle/commEnv.sh /u01/oracle/wlserver/common/bin/commEnv.sh && \
    rm /u01/oracle/create-wls-domain.py /u01/oracle/jaxrs2-template.jar 


COPY log4j.properties /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/

EXPOSE $NM_PORT $ADMIN_PORT $MS_PORT 5005
# Expose Node Manager default port, and also default http/https ports for admin console

WORKDIR $DOMAIN_HOME 


# Define default command to start bash. 
CMD ["startWebLogic.sh"]
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run -d --name webapp -p 7007:7007 -p 7003:7003 -p 5556:5556 -v /c/webapp:/webapp 1213-domain
```

By the way I'm using weblogic 12.1.3 image for this deployment.

Comment: You have not included enough information for anyone to help you. How are you starting the containers? Are you exporting ports? Are they on the same Docker bridge network? You need to include stuff like `docker run` commands, or docker-compose.yml if you are using it...

Comment: @DanLowe Yes they are on the same Docker bridge network. and Yes the port 5556 is exposed and the machine worker is reachable from Master machine So I guess there is no communication problem between the machines.

Comment: I'm not sure what port 5556 is, your screenshot seems to care about port 7003 being unreachable. Is 7003 exposed?

Comment: @DanLowe Port 5556 is where the Node Manager is running and Yes I have exposed the port 7003.


I'm experiencing the same problem even if both the admin server and managed servers running on the same machine this is bit weird -_- .

Comment: You still haven't posted anything such as Dockerfile, `docker run` commands, docker-compose.yml. This makes it hard for anyone to do anything except make guesses.

Comment: @DanLowe I have updated the topic with the docker file and the docker run command please go through them and help me out if you can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You said you had two machines involved. The edits are about a single container. Are you running this single container on each of two separate machines, and you want those machines to communicate? Or something else?

Comment: @DanLowe Yes that's the image both the machines use and that's the command used on both the machines to start the weblogic.

Comment: In that case I would look at whether the two machines are capable of finding each others addresses in DNS, making sure the system firewalls allow this traffic through, and so on... something on one or both machines may be stopping the connection from being made.

Comment: performed ping and telnet, both are communicating with each other. And even the Node Manager running on Worker1 at 5556 is reachable from Master machine. I'm not sure what is wrong :(